# Пишу телеграм бота с БД MySQL. Появляется ошибка - MySQL Connection not available"

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Использую библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI + python 3.7.6 (Windows 10).
Я написал достаточно огромный код, и в нём есть большое количество sql-запросов.  Ошибка появляется, когда вовремя не выполняется sql-запрос. Я попытался открывать/закрывать курсор после каждого запроса, и это только частично решило мою проблему. Как можно реализовать в коде, чтобы sql-запрос всегда завершался, прежде чем пользователь сделает какие-либо действия, то есть добавить какое-то явное ожидание? 
Приведу пример в коде.

Так как всё происходит в бесконечном цикле бота - то кнопки в моём коде  постоянно "прослушиваются". И если пользователь нажмет быстро на две кнопки сразу - произойдет ошибка.

```
if message.text == 'Пример 1':
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "INSERT INTO orders (user_id,item) VALUES (%s,%s)"
        val = (message.chat.id ,'Пример 1')
        result = cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()  
        cursor.close()
        return next(message)
elif message.text == 'Пример 2':
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "INSERT INTO orders (user_id, item) VALUES (%s,%s)"
        val = (message.chat.id,'Пример 2')
        result = cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        return for_shop(message)
```

Comment: Значит, нажатие любой кнопки должно блокировать все кнопки до завершения обработки нажатия. Или выставлять флаг "не слушать" либо "слушать, но игнорировать" - по вкусу.

Comment: @Akina, как посоветуете реализовать блокирование кнопок?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось всё намного проще. Для любителей быстро нажимать на кнопки я предусмотрел блок исключений try-except.
Может кому-то пригодится - насчет sql-запросов я решил переключить бота в однопоточный режим, так как мой бот ориентирован на небольшое количество пользователей:
`bot = telebot.TeleBot('your token', threaded=False)`. Это если пойти простым путём и не заморачиваться.

UPD.
Решение всё-таки нашлось!!! Думаю это точно кому-то пригодится.
Если бот работает у вас в многопоточном режиме - достаточно взять ваше подключение к БД в функцию и вызывать перед sql-запросом.

```
def conn():
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host = "your host",
        user = "user",
        passwd = "your pswd",
        port = "your port",
        database = "example"
        )
    return db
    ...
```

```
...
db = conn()
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO orders (user_id, item) VALUES (%s,%s)"
val = (message.chat.id, 'Пример 1')
result = cursor.execute(sql, val)
db.commit()
```