# Почему не удаляется сообщение бота в чате?

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

1. Есть telegram-bot на aiogram и sqlite.
2. Есть алгоритм, удаляющий присланную только-что команду пользователем и предыдущее сообщение, отправленное ботом пользователю, являющееся ответом на предыдущую команду пользователя.

   2.1 id сообщения бота записывается в базу данных пользователя.

   2.2 Алгоритм извлекает из БД id и по нему удаляет сообщение.

   2.3 Сам алгоритм:

   ```
   async def del_last_bot_message(*args):
   '''
   Удаление лишних сообщений для реализации "чистого интерфейса"
   '''
       print(f'ENTER MESSAGE: {args[0].message_id + 1}')

   # Удаление сообщения пользователя
       try:
           await args[0].delete()
       except:
           Exception

   # Удаление последнего сообщения бота по id
       bmi = dict(ast.literal_eval(database.select_user_data(args[0])))
       while len(bmi['bot_mes_id']) > 0:
           bmi = dict(ast.literal_eval(database.select_user_data(args[0])))
           for ids in bmi['bot_mes_id']:
               try:
                   print(f'TRY DEL MES: {ids} OF {args[0].from_user.username}')
                   await bot.delete_message(args[0].chat.id, ids)
                   print(f'DONE DEL MES: {ids} OF {args[0].from_user.username}')
                   database.del_bmi_element(args[0], ids)
                   print(f'DONE DEL ELEM: {ids} OF {args[0].from_user.username}')
               except:
                   print(f'FAILE DEL MESSAGE: {ids} OF {args[0].from_user.username}')
                   continue
       if len(bmi['bot_mes_id']) == 0:
           database.create_bmi_in_user_data(args[0])
           print(f'LAST FOO: {args[0].message_id + 1} {args[0].from_user.username}')
   ```

   2.4 Алгоритм создания id сообщения и помещения его в БД:

   ```
   class DataBase():
   ...
       def create_bmi_in_user_data(self, message):
       '''Создание id сообщения бота и помещение его в user_data'''
           user_data_dict = dict(ast.literal_eval(database.select_user_data(message)))
           try:
               user_id = message.chat.id
           except:
               user_id = message.from_user.id
           user_data_dict['bot_mes_id'].append(message.message_id + 1)
           try:
               with self.connection:
                   return self.cursor.execute(f'''UPDATE users_table SET user_data = "{user_data_dict}" WHERE user_id = "{user_id}"''')
           except:
               Exception

       def del_bmi_element(self, message, element):
       '''Удаление id сообщения бота из словаря и возвращение словаря в user_data'''
           user_data_dict = dict(ast.literal_eval(database.select_user_data(message)))
           try:
               user_id = message.chat.id
           except:
               user_id = message.from_user.id
           user_data_dict['bot_mes_id'].remove(element)
           with self.connection:
               return self.cursor.execute(f'''UPDATE users_table SET user_data = "{user_data_dict}" WHERE user_id = "{user_id}"''')

       def select_user_data(self, message):
       '''Выделение user_data пользователя в БД'''
           try:
               user_id = message.chat.id
           except:
               user_id = message.from_user.id
           with self.connection:
               return self.cursor.execute(f'''SELECT user_data FROM users_table WHERE user_id = "{user_id}"''').fetchone()[0]
   ```

   2.5 Ситуация в терминале ("Чистый запуск" с обнулённой БД и историей чата):
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Исходя из данных импровизированных логов, представленных выше, и работы бота, алгоритм работает как надо и для каждого пользователя, всё окей.
4. Проблема появляется, когда два и более пользователей ОДНОВРЕМЕННО присылают команду боту. После неё, алгоритм так же срабатывает как надо, но при следующей отправке команды перестаёт работать.

   4.1 Логи:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   4.2 Исходя из логов, алгоритм не может удалить сообщение по id и пытается это сделать бесконечное количество раз, что очень странно, так как сообщение бота, соответствующее используемому id существует в чате:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   4.3 Если убрать конструкцию try/except из алгоритма 2.3 пункта, интерпретатор выдаёт ошибку

   > File "..\main.py", line 1503, in del_last_bot_message await
   > bot.delete_message(args[0].chat.id, ids)
   > aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageToDeleteNotFound: Message to delete
   > not found

3й день ломаю голову над проблемой, не понимаю, в чём дело.
Дополню информацию, если необходимо.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Сложно разобраться - все как-то нагружено, много лишнего... 1) Зачем выносить одно действие для удаления значения из словаря в отельный метод? 2) В пункте 2.4 что вам возвращает метод `del_bmi_element`, если используете `UPDATE`? - Объект курсора, если конечно не приходится использовать его в последующих целях. 3) Вот например, зачем вам в 2.3 - два цикла (`while` и `for`), мне кажется, можно обойтись и одним `for` (если верно понял алгоритм). 4) Код подвержен sql-инъекциям, может в данном коде не прокатит, но в других случаях - прощай база данных:).  Используйте `?` вместо форматирования `f`.

Comment: А вообще могу предположить, что проблема связана с неправильным использованием словарей (но это только мое предположение)

Comment: @DeNRuDi  1) Посчитал, что так удобнее. 2) Да, лишнее действие оказалось. 3) С одним `for` алгоритм не работает как надо. 4) Момент учту, спасибо. Однако, проблема не решилась.

Comment: хм, так вы же написали, что если одновременно нажимают два юзера - все гуд, но после этого начинает уже выводиться ошибка. Уверены, что при следующем удалении в базе уже находится новый `message_id`? Я бы в вашем случае воспользовался дебаггером, например из PyCharm-a, чтоб отследить каждую операцию, а не писал бы свои логи, для БД скачал бы SQLiteStudio для анализа. Хотя примерно подобное поведение кода когда-то и у меня было, но там была `MySQL`, но алгоритм решения и для SQLite один и тот же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1082788/331443.